# about html <button> tag

Tags: html, button, web

I am trying to use the HTML button tag. But I have a doubt :

The button should not always appear but appear only if some condition is satisfied. How can I implement this ?

Specifically:

The user searches my database. The records which are in the result are shown as a table. These records are event listings and the user can register only for some of the events depending upon some condition. 
Registration of any event is made possible by a button click "Register". How can I make the button appear next to only the records for which that user is eligible to register ?

Comment: Just use an `if` block in your server side view technology?

Comment: Use a server-side script.  PHP, JSP, ASP, whatever you want.  You can then decide whether you're putting in an enabled or disabled button.

Answer (score 1):

You should display or not the button while you generate the html page, namely **on the server side**. 
Don't forget to check later **on the server side** if the user is authorized to register before doing the actual registration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an input tag if it's going to be used to submit a form. You have the option of either hiding it conditionally on the server side depending on what language you're using, or hiding it through JavaScript on the browser side.

Server side is preferable because the condition is being generated on that side. It also prevents the user from tampering with things browser side. I'd also make sure that subsequent stages verifies eligibility, and doesn't just rely on the presence of a button.

Comment: "It also prevents the user from tampering with things browser side." WHAT?!?

Comment: If you disable something with JavaScript or CSS, someone can always inspect the DOM and display it again or re-insert the element. Also if JavaScript breaks then all of a sudden a bunch of hidden elements get exposed. In short if you don't want someone touching a button, don't even have it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine whether the user can register for the event on the server, then only emit the `<button>` in that case.

If you can only determine this on the client side for some reason (eg: their eligibility is based on some other information they've entered) then you could programmatically set the CSS `display` property to `none` to make the button disappear, though it might make more sense to simply disable the button in that case.

Comment: Do you mean the "disable" attribute in the button tag ?

Comment: @Nihit yes. The behavior is different: a disabled button is generally visible (unless you've done something interesting in your stylesheet) but might make more sense for the case where the user can enter something in the form to become eligible for registration.